# UNET : DSC and IOU for segmentation

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, image-segmentation

I have been trying to train UNET with **binary crossentropy** as loss and reading **dice_coeff** and **iou** as metrics during training and validation. The result after 5 epochs is

```
Epoch 5/5 2373/2373 [==============================] - 84s 35ms/step - loss: 0.0260 - dice_coef: 0.9864 - iou: 0.9734 - val_loss: 0.0579 - val_dice_coef: 0.9583 - val_iou: 0.9216
```

The metrics I used are here:

```
def iou(y_true, y_pred):
  def f(y_true, y_pred):
    intersection = (y_true * y_pred).sum()
    union = y_true.sum() + y_pred.sum() - intersection
    x = (intersection + 1e-15) / (union + 1e-15)
    x = x.astype(np.float32)
    return x
return tf.numpy_function(f, [y_true, y_pred], tf.float32)

smooth = 1e-15
def dice_coef(y_true, y_pred):
    y_true = tf.keras.layers.Flatten()(y_true)
    y_pred = tf.keras.layers.Flatten()(y_pred)
    intersection = tf.reduce_sum(y_true * y_pred)
    return (2. * intersection + smooth) / (tf.reduce_sum(y_true) + tf.reduce_sum(y_pred) + smooth)

def dice_loss(y_true, y_pred):
    return 1.0 - dice_coef(y_true, y_pred)
```

The evaluation result is here

```
46/46 [==============================] - 12s 259ms/step - loss: 0.0557 - dice_coef: 0.9567 - iou: 0.9181
```

***My doubt here is***

1. Even though I get 95% dice and iou of 91%, the predicted masks are not as expected. They predicted a lot of area for most of the images. I wonder how this 95% is obtained. There are many images where the predictions are not reasonable.
2. As far as I know, the training and validation results give a mean dice score. the predicted mask will have values between [0,1]. What is usually reported in papers? is it after applying threshold>0.5 or before threshold? Can't we train the network with a metric that takes threshold as well? If yes, please help me with the code.
   The result of a test image after evaluating the model is given below:

[image: prediction and ground truth]

Comment: can you compute IoU and Dice score for the example you show? Does it have significantly high scores while you expect them to be lower? Or is this instance has a lower score, as expected?

Comment: If I calculate dice between the predicted mask after thresholding and ground truth, it is somewhere around 50% which is reasonably good. But the mean of all dice scores obtained from predictions after thresholding is around 30%. and before thresholding, the mean dice score is just 2%. In any case, it cannot be 95% as obtained from evaluation results.

Comment: try computing the dice score/IoU for the thresholded and non-thresholded predictions and see the difference. You might want to add a term in your loss that encourages the predictions to be closer to {0,1} rather than intermediate values in between. My guess is that your predictions are very close to 0.5 with only minor fluctuations.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to take the threshold into account, you need to draw the [ROC curve](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Receiver_operating_characteristic). For binary classification (per pixel) the ROC curve shows you how accuracy and specificity change with the threshold.
Once you have an ROC curve, you can measure the ["area under the curve"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Receiver_operating_characteristic#Area_under_the_curve) to get a single number evaluating your classifier.

You can use [`sklearn.metrics.roc_curve`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.roc_curve.html#sklearn.metrics.roc_curve) implementation to compute it.